# Updating listview on fragment

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a `ListView` that has a `SwipeRefreshLayout` implemented on it. What I am trying to do is update the `ListView` when the user swipes down. I've tried looking for different options but unfortunately I am unable to find a solution.

Would it be better to reload the `Fragment` or the `onCreate` function?

**Here is my code**

```
public class NewsTab extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener{
final LinkedList<News> listnews = new LinkedList<News>();


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_tab, container, false);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        newslist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.displaynews);

        populatelist(listnews);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),listnews);
        newslist.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view; 
}

public void onRefresh() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    new StartNewsLoad().execute("");
}

private class StartNewsLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //ProgressDialog pd = null;
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        reloadNews();
        loadTopNews();
        //NewsTab.listnews = new LinkedList<News>();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),listnews);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

**///ANSWER**

I found the answer! I added the following line of code inside my costume adapter and called it outside as adapter.refresh();

```
public void refresh(LinkedList<News> newsList)
    {
        this.results = newsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: You need to set the adapter on the ListView before you notify it

Comment: Other than that, where does `listnews` come from? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for your response listnews is a global linked list i created that holds my news class please see edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all no need to create the adapter again in `onPostExecute()` as you have already initialized it in `onCreateView()`.You simple need to notify the adapter of the changes in the "listnews" if it has changed.Make sure that your list actually changes before calling the `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Also please use debugger or log to check whether your `onRefresh()` is called or not.From the way i see, it should be overriden with @override annotation as it is the method of the interface implemented by your fragment(`swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);`).It should be like:

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    new StartNewsLoad().execute("");
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response, adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),listnews); im adding it like this in order to add the new list is there a way to just to what i have already?

Comment: @paul590 you are doing fine when creating the adapter but when you need to update the list view do not create it again or set it again on listview.Simple call notifydatasetchanged when the data in your arraylist  changes.

Comment: thank you for providing me with this information i removed the listview.setadapter(adapter) line and ket the notifydatasetchanged but my list did not update with the new values, i tested the values were added by scrolling to another tab that pulls the same information and the new ones were dead, am I missing a commit line or anything that initiates the update of the list?

Comment: thank you for your help i found my answer see above!

Answer (score 1):

In onCreateView() intialize your listview and swiperefereshLayout with listener and set your adapter to your listview like that --->

```
if(adapter==null&& listNews==null){
listnews=new ArrayList<object>();
adapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),listnews);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
else{
listView.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

this way it also handle retaining the listData onOrientationchange.

and **when you get api response or referesh listview with swipe layout,dont create new adapter just add listNews to your adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

Comment: thank you for your response, how would i got about adding to the adapter instead of recreating it?

Comment: hello after trying to apply your recommendation, I am still not able to see the list update, I have removed the setadapter line and kept the adapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),listnews) and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but no luck

Comment: thank you for your help i found my answer see above!